# How I can send attachment along with comment to Jira using Jira Rest API

Tags: .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I am calling two separate endpoints to send attachment to Jira with comment.

1. `/rest/api/3/issue/{issueKey}/attachments`
2. `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/comment`

I am sending the attachment first, and retrieving the attachment Id. Then I call `post` request for comment and I bind `attachment Id` to the comment body and send comment. But it is not working in this way.

Here are my upload attachment, and post comment function of .NET  application.

```
[HttpPost("postcommentwithattachmentonjira")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCommentWithAttachmentOnJiraIssue(string issueKey, string commentBody, List<IFormFile> files)
{
        try
        {
            // Step 1: Upload the file as an attachment
            var attachmentId = await UploadAttachment(issueKey, files);

            // Step 2: Add a comment with a link to the attachment
            commentBody += $" [^{attachmentId}]";
            return await AddCommentOnJiraIssue(issueKey, commentBody);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any exception that occurred during the process
            return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
}

// add attachment endpoint
private async Task<string> UploadAttachment(string issueKey, List<IFormFile> files)
{
        try
        {
            string url = $"{JiraBaseUrl}/rest/api/3/issue/{issueKey}/attachments";

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{JiraUsername}:{JiraApiToken}"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check"); // Add the header

                // Create a multipart form data content
                using (var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                            byte[] fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
                            multipartContent.Add(fileContent, "file", file.FileName);
                        }
                    }

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multipartContent);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var responseObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(responseContent);
                    string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseObject);
                    JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);

                    if (jsonDocument.RootElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array && jsonDocument.RootElement.GetArrayLength() > 0)
                    {
                        JsonElement firstElement = jsonDocument.RootElement[0];
                        if (firstElement.TryGetProperty("id", out JsonElement idElement) && idElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
                        {
                            return idElement.GetString();
                        }
                    }

                    throw new Exception("Failed to extract attachment ID from the response.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to upload attachment to Jira issue. Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
}

// add comment end point
private async Task<IActionResult> AddCommentOnJiraIssue(string issueKey, string commentBody)
{
        string url = $"{JiraBaseUrl}/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/comment";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = new StringContent($"{{ \"body\": \"{commentBody}\" }}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{JiraUsername}:{JiraApiToken}"));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {authHeaderValue}");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            var responseObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonResponse, jsonOptions);
            return Ok(responseObject);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, "Failed to post comment on Jira issue.");
        }
}
```

In Jira the comment appears like this:

[image]

Is there any other way other way to send attachment to Jira using its REST API ? Or is there a mistake in sending attachment with this approach?